# XMonad gaps in fullscreen

Tags: window-manager, xmonad, haskell

I am trying to set up XMonad so that multiple windows have gaps between them. The relevant part of my config file is as follows

```
import XMonad.Layout.Spacing
```

followed later by

```
myLayout = tiled ||| Mirror tiled ||| Full
  where
    tiled = spacing 5 $ Tall nmaster delta ratio
    nmaster = 1
    ratio = 1/2
    delta = 3/100
```

The problem is that when one window occupied the whole screen there are gaps along the border. Is there a way to adjust my configuration so that these gaps do not appear when there is only one window?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at `smartSpacing`: (see [Xmonad Spacing Docs](http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/XMonad-Layout-Spacing.html))

> Surrounds all windows with blank space, except when the window is the
>   only visible window on the current workspace.

I.e., changing

```
tiled = spacing 5 $ Tall nmaster delta ratio
```

to

```
tiled = smartSpacing 5 $ Tall nmaster delta ratio
```

should to the trick.

Comment: spacingRaw should be used now: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.16/docs/XMonad-Layout-Spacing.html